# "Access Denied" on certain SharePoint SSP links

Tags: sharepoint, ssp

I've been attempting to configure some links on the SSP home page. Most of these, including search admin, work fine. However the following give me an "Access Denied" error:

- User profiles and properties
- Profile services policies
- My Site settings
- Audiences

I've tried using the farm administrator account, SSP account, SSP web app account, and my own account which is a local administrator. Nothing is appearing in the ULS logs.

The only thing I know that might have caused this is that the service accounts were changed from local accounts to domain accounts.

Any ideas on what this could be or how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a clever move on my part, I actually disabled access for myself in the **Personalization services permissions** page. Also the service account changes had not added the domain accounts that are now being used into this page.

Solution was simply to add/modify permissions to the service accounts and myself.

Comment: Goofy the way that works, no?  For what it's worth, I've tripped over that one myself before  :-)